# Remove element by value in Go list

Tags: list, go, slice

I have a list of elements and I want to remove one of them, by value. In Python this would be

```
l = ["apples", "oranges", "melon"]
l.remove("melon")
print(l) # ["apples", "orange"]
```

What is the equivalent in Go? I found a [slice trick](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks) to remove an element by index, but it's not very readable, still requires me to find the index manually and only works for a single item type:

```
func remove(l []string, item string) {
    for i, other := range l {
        if other == item {
            return append(l[:i], l[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
}
```

There's the [`list.List`](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks) structure, but it's not generic and thus requires tons of type-castings to use.

What is the idiomatic way of removing an element from a list?

Comment: let me clarify, you need to remove an item from slice or the container list  ?

Comment: I currently have a slice, but I'm willing to replace it with a container list or anything else that does the job.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The idiomatic way to remove an element from a list is to loop through it exactly like you do in your example. Removing an element by value from a slice shouldn't be too common in your program since it is an `O(n)` operation and there are better data structures in the language for that. Therefore, Go does not provide a built-in remove function for slices.

If you find yourself using removal by value often, consider using a set instead where removing and adding an element is `O(1)` while still being  iterable.

```
set := map[string]bool{"apples":true, "oranges":true, "melon":true}
delete(set,"melon") // is O(1)
```

Comment: I would argue that using a set-based approach is not always suitable, because set is generally unordered. So when the task is: "remove element by value from a sorted data collection", set won't help.

Answer (score 9):

In generic Go (1.18) the filter function works on any `comparable` type. It removes only the *first* occurrence of the item.

```
func remove[T comparable](l []T, item T) []T {
    for i, other := range l {
        if other == item {
            return append(l[:i], l[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
    return l
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/ojlYkvf5dQG?v=gotip

---

If you want to remove *all* occurrences, append the items that *don't* match to a new slice:

```
func remove[T comparable](l []T, item T) []T {
    out := make([]T, 0)
    for _, element := range l {
        if element != item {
            out = append(out, element)
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/W2MerNbh72H

---

If the slice items aren't comparable, you can use a custom equality function to filter:

```
func main() {
    list := [][]int{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 10}}
    newlist := remove(list, func(element []int) bool { return element[0] == 1 })
    fmt.Println(newlist)
}

func remove[T any](l []T, remove func(T) bool) []T {
    out := make([]T, 0)
    for _, element := range l {
        if !remove(element) {
            out = append(out, element)
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/qZWoFbM_RUl